# Can you make a recyclerview that allows scrolling both horizontally and vertically

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I currently have a recyclerview that goes vertically on the page, but I need additional data for each element in that recyclerview to be represented on the page by scrolling horizontally as well. The attached image displays what I currently have, and diagrams what I need.[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHvPS.jpg)
The following are the 2 xml files in charge of creating that display.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Team_Yearly_Stats">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wait"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Please Wait"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="W"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.181"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:text="L"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wins"
                android:layout_width="57dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="-40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Sample Title"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.331"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/loses"
                android:layout_width="113dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Sample Title"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/wins"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="53dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Sample Description for the given title"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/wins"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.04"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can there are various libraries like https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView but there are various sizing issues with this one.

Or shameless plug https://github.com/Zardozz/FixedHeaderTableLayout though this is not a recycler View but it does not have the sizing issues that come with a recycler based view and it offers zooming (not available on recycler based views).